# How JVM is invoked?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to learn Java. I was going through many documents. I understood that, wen we give **javac** command, the files are compiled and Bytecodes are produced.
 After this we are giving **java** command to Run the program.

- I want to know what is happening in the background?
- I mean how Jvm is invoked?
- who is invoking the JVM?
- How classes are getting loaded?

Comment: Have you gone through [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `java` command will launch the JVM. I am not sure if the two can be considered synonymous, but for all intents and purposes this is the result.

When the JVM is launched, the classes are loaded into memory and then the main class is executed. The specifics of the JVM execution are rather complicated and IMO not fit for a single question. As TS- pointed out, the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) is out there.

Comment: The java application launcher is part of Jdk rite? If we want to run a .class file we need to hav both JDK and JRE or JRE alone is enough?

Comment: The JRE (which contains the JVM) is enough to launch an application. The JDK is simply a suite of development tools like the compiler.

Comment: Where does this java.exe resides? in jdk or JRE?

Comment: @TFool: It's in the JRE.

Comment: who will load the class and who will call the main method? It is the JVM or the java command?